# Mongoose.js not removing object from array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

I'm using Mongoose with my Discord bot and I'm making the feature where the infractions can be removed from any mentioned user(s).

The infractions are saved in an `Array`

However, when trying to remove the object from the array, nothing happens, no error.

Here is my code

**What `foundCase` is defined as** *(returns this object)*

```js
{
  type: 'warn',
  caseNum: 6,
  userID: '300816697282002946',
  responsibleModerator: '300816697282002946',
  reason: 'playing minecraft',
  date: 1592678689923
}
```

**My code**

```js
let foundCase = message.guild.data.infractions.find(c => {
                        return c.userID === calledMember.user.id && c.caseNum === Number(caseNum);
                    })

                    if (!foundCase)
                        return message.channel.send(`There were no cases found with that ID to remove from this user. Please ensure the case number is correct, and the user you are mentioning is the right user.`)



                    console.log(foundCase)
                    await client.guildData.updateOne( { guildData: message.guild.id }, { $pull: { infractions: foundCase }})
                    message.channel.send(`I have successfully deleted case number \`${caseNum}\`, and removed the infraction from the user. The change will reflect in any reports within 5 mins.`)
```

However, nothing happens. The infraction is not removed at all and is still in the array.

Does anybody have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

it maybe the case that your foundCase returns and empty object if no Id matches so to be safe change this line `if (!foundCase)` to this `if(foundCase.userId=="undefined")`

also you can try this

```
client.guildData.updateOne( { guildData: message.guild.id }, { $pull: { infractions: "foundCase"}})
```

or this

```
client.guildData.updateOne( { guildData: message.guild.id }, { $pull:{infractions: { $in: [ "foundCase"] }}})
```

Comment: In the testing at the time it was a full object, so I know that's not the problem

Comment: Let me try both of these and see what happens

Comment: Nope, none of these worked. Same result on each. Nothing happens at all